# How do I choose which Page starts first in Windows Phone 8

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8, interpreter, geocode

I'm making a weather app in windows phone 8. I use geolocation to get my coordinates and use reverseCoordinates to get it into a city name, which later on I intend to use for my url which I use for getting my weather data.

This is the code for my reverseCoordinates and it is in my mainpage.xaml.cs

```
public static string City;

public void reverseGeocode_QueryCompleted(object sender, QueryCompletedEventArgs<IList<MapLocation>> e)
{
    MapAddress geoAddress = e.Result[0].Information.Address;
    City = geoAddress.City;
    txtStad.Text = City;
}
```

In my MainViewModel, (where I have to get my City on),the code I use is

```
   string City = WeatherApp1.MainPage.City;
```

Now the problem is, when I debug I can see that the interpreter first uses my mainviewmodel, but then when I use my code, City had the value null, because it hasn't been done yet in Mainpage.xaml.cs. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

Comment: how about where you get the user to choose a city, set it to a default value (i.e. if they fill in a textbox have 'London' already in it).

Answer (score 0):

What you need to do is open up `WMAppManifest.xml` and change the value of Navigation Page to what ever page you need. eg. Page1.xaml

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that when the method which relies on City value is executed only when it has a value. Another solution would be to assing some default value. You can make use of ?? operator like this:

```
string City = WeatherApp1.MainPage.City ?? "London";
```

How it works? When WeatherApp1.MainPage.City is null then ?? will set City to London.

Also take a look at this article on how to pass values between pages:
http://www.geekchamp.com/tips/how-to-pass-data-between-pages-in-windows-phone-alternatives